# twitter api and tkinter - python 2.7.8

Tags: python, twitter, tkinter

I am streaming tweets in a GUI program. Each tweet is appended to a TEXT widget of Tkinter. The code is as follows :

```
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
import time
import json
from threading import Thread
from Tkinter import *


ckey='xxx'
csecret='xxx'
atoken='xxx'
asecret='xxx'

tweetQ=[]

tweet_no=0
stream_created=0

def processT(tweet):
    global tweet_no
    global tweet_box
    tweet_no+=1
    if 'text' in tweet:
        text = tweet['text'].encode('ascii', 'ignore')
        date = tweet['created_at']
        tweet_box.insert(END,str(tweet_no)+"\t"+str(date)+"\t"+str(text)+"\n")
        tweet_box.update_idletasks()
        tweet_box.yview(END)

class listener(StreamListener):
    def on_data(self,data):
        try:
            tweet=json.loads(data)
            t=Thread(target=processT,args=(tweet,))
            t.start()
            t.join()
            return True

        except BaseException ,e:
            print "Failed on_data, ",str(e)

    def on_error(self,status):
        print status
        time.sleep(3)

def actFromTo(i):
    if i==0:
        option_real.select()
        option_time.deselect()
    else:
        option_real.deselect()
        option_time.select()



def main():
    global stream_created
    try:
        auth = OAuthHandler(ckey,csecret)
        auth.set_access_token(atoken,asecret)
        if stream_created==0:
            stream_created=1
            twitterStream=Stream(auth,listener())
            twitterStream.filter(locations=[-122.75,36.8,-121.75,37.8,-74,40,-73,41])
        else:
            delete(twitterStream)


    except BaseException ,e:
        stream_created=0
        print "Failed main, ",str(e)



root= Tk()
root.title("Twitter Monitor")

left_f = Frame(root)
right_f = Frame(root)


v = StringVar()
v.set(["selection"])
option_real = Radiobutton(left_f,variable=v,text="Realtime",value=1,command=lambda:actFromTo(0))
option_real.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky=(W))
option_real.select()
option_time=Radiobutton(left_f,variable=v,text="Time period",value=2,command=lambda:actFromTo(1))
option_time.grid(row=1,column=0,sticky=(W))
frm = Label(left_f,text="FROM > ")
frm.grid(row=2,column=1,sticky=(E))
frm_f = Entry(left_f,width=10,state=DISABLED)
frm_f.grid(row=2,column=2,sticky=(E))

to = Label(left_f,text="TO > ")
to.grid(row=2,column=3,sticky=(E))
to_f = Entry(left_f,width=10,state=DISABLED)
to_f.grid(row=2,column=4,sticky=(E))


tweet_box = Text(right_f,width=80)

scrollbar = Scrollbar(right_f, orient="vertical")
scrollbar.config(command=tweet_box.yview)

tweet_box.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
scrollbar.pack(side='right')
tweet_box.pack(side='right')

launch = Button(left_f,text="<< START >>",command=main)
launch.grid(row=3,column=0,sticky=(E))


left_f.pack(side=LEFT,padx=20,pady=20)
right_f.pack(side=RIGHT,padx=20,pady=20)
root.mainloop()
```

I have a **start** button which initiates the process of streaming. The program is working fine but as soon as I touch the GUI window or press start button again or use the scrollbar , the program goes to NOT RESPONDING state.

I am using Windows 7 32 bit and Python 2.7.8. What can be the possible reasons?. I even tried creating a separate thread for executing the process but problem persists...

Comment: hey @ranger, you have the auth params fully visible in your question. Just wanted to let you know. Not sure if that was intentional.

Comment: If you are running your app without a console (normal), start it from a Command Prompt window: `> python path-to-app`.  You might then see error messages sent to the console.

Comment: @TerryJanReedy: I have tried this C:\python27\python myprog.py. Its not showing any error but gets in to non reponding stage once I move the window or click on scroll bar. note : The keys are shown as XXX for security reasons

Answer (score 0):

Tkinter isn't thread-safe. You can only access the methods of a widget from the same thread that creates the widget.

Comment: what if i am accessing the widget from a different function?

Comment: Different functions are fine, different threads is not. You're calling `processT` from a thread.

Comment: Earlier I didnt use any threads.At that time also the GUI got into non responding state when touched the scroll bar or moved the window

Comment: There is some controversy over tkinter and thread-safety.  One of the developers has said it is intended to be thread-safe, as least is widgets are created in main thread.  I have not tested the claim.

Comment: @TerryJanReedy: I don't see much controversy. One developer says it should work, lots of questions on SO and other sites show many people with behaviors very typical to code that isn't thread safe.

Comment: See `http://bugs.python.org/issue11077` for discussion.  For me, the test example only works for 3.4.2, not 2.7.8, so the answer depends on the python version.